# PHP evaluation for "Send HTML email body"

Tags: 7, rules, emails

I'm trying to compose the body of an email using PHP evaluation within a rule.  The rule is triggered when a new content is saved.  Part of the email body is composed using HEREDOC and that works fine.  This is the code I'm having trouble with:

```
//  Provide download link.
 if ($node->field_software_product_sku === "Some Product Name")
     echo "<a href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/Some Product Name/some.exe\">Trial Version Download Link</a><br />";
```

The above code comes directly after the ending of the HEREDOC, but, before the closing '**?>**'.  I anticipate that in the future, I will need to add more clauses to the 'if' statement, so, it's important that I get this to work.

I've tried several different incantations for coding the 'if'.  I've tried using the token name enclosed in single quotes.  And, I've tried using “==” instead of “===”.  The only thing that seems to work consistently is commenting out the 'if'.  Then, the “*Trial Download Link*” text does appear in the email.  Unfortunately, the rule is to be used for multiple “skus”, so, I need to use the 'if'.

I'm hoping I've made a subtle mistake, or, overlooked something.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Is there a way to debug the code to see why the 'if' may be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `field_software_product_sku` is text field you should test on value of the field something like:

```
if ($node->field_software_product_sku[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] === "Some Product Name"){
    echo "<a href=\"http://www.mywebsite.com/Some Product Name/some.exe\">Trial Version Download Link</a><br />";
  }
```

other ways if it doesn't work, i suggest you to use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Module and dump the `$node->field_software_product_sku` using [dpm](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7.x-1.x) function to see the value of the field:
`dpm($node->field_software_product_sku)` and then check on the value of the field.

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  I knew I had missed something obvious.

Comment: Great, marked as accepted, to help other.